# Persistent Store save boolean as objects

Tags: object, blackberry, persistent, persistent-storage

I am developing a BlackBerry App and saving a lot of values as `String` and `boolean` to the `Persistent Store`. I am aware of the fact that String and boolean values do not get deleted from Persistent when an App is deleted/uninstalled from the handset. I am also aware of the fact that in order to delete these values I need to store this in a "project" specific class. I have been struggling with it and so would want a **temporary** work around. I am saving a boolean value in order to determine which screen the App should load it.

```
PersistentStoreHelper.persistentHashtable.put("flagged",Boolean.TRUE); 

if (PersistentStoreHelper.persistentHashtable.containsKey("flagged")) 
        {
           boolean booleanVal = ((Boolean) PersistentStoreHelper.persistentHashtable.get("flagged")).booleanValue();
           if (booleanVal==true)
           {
              pushScreen(new MyScreen());
           }
        }
        else
        {
            pushScreen(new MyScreen(false));
        }
```

Is it possible to store this boolean value as an Object so that it gets deleted when the App is uninstalled/deleted. Please help as well as comment if I am missing out on anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again, I'd recommend you change your `PersistentStoreHelper` to [this version online](http://pastebin.com/tka4jQvF).

You certainly can get `Boolean` and `String` values to be deleted from the persistent store when your app is uninstalled, but they need to be **inside** an object that can only exist in your app.

For example:

```java
 PersistentStoreHelper store = PersistentStoreHelper.getInstance();
 store.put("flagged", Boolean.TRUE);
 // commit will save changes to the `flagged` variable
 store.commit();
```

and then retrieve it later with:

```java
 PersistentStoreHelper store = PersistentStoreHelper.getInstance();
 boolean isFlagged = ((Boolean)store.get("flagged")).booleanValue();
```

The key that makes this work is inside my `PersistentStoreHelper` class, it saves everything inside a **subclass** of `Hashtable` that's unique to my/your app (`MyAppsHashtable`).  You need to store your `String` or `Boolean` objects inside that app-unique `Hashtable` subclass, **not** in a normal `java.util.Hashtable`.

Again, please make this easy on yourself, and use the code I posted.

**Note:** also, you probably know this, but you may need to reboot your device to see the app, and its persistent store data, fully deleted.

### Update

If you had changed the original `PersistentStoreHelper` class that [I had posted online](http://pastebin.com/tka4jQvF), because you wanted access to the `containsKey()` method, or other methods in the `Hashtable` class, you can solve that problem by simply adding code like this:

```java
public boolean containsKey(String key) {
    return persistentHashtable.containsKey(key);
}
```

to the `PeristentStoreHelper` class.  **Please don't** make `persistentHashtable` a `public static` member.  As you need to use more `Hashtable` methods, just add *wrappers* for them, like I show above with `containsKey()`.  Of course, you can achieve the same thing as `containsKey()` by simply using this code:

```java
 boolean containsFlagged = (store.get("flagged") != null);
```

### Update 2

If you get stuck with old persistent data, that you need to clean out, you can modify `PersistentStoreHelper` to detect and correct the situation, like this (hattip to @adwiv for suggestions):

```java
   private PersistentStoreHelper() {
      persistentObject = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(KEY);

      Object contents = persistentObject.getContents();
      if (contents instanceof MyAppsHashtable) {
         persistentHashtable = (MyAppsHashtable)contents;
      } else {
         // store might be empty, or contents could be the wrong type
         persistentHashtable = new MyAppsHashtable();
         persistentObject.setContents(persistentHashtable);
         persistentObject.commit();
      }
   }
```

Comment: thank you for the details. Please note while the App is running on the simulator (persistent data however not deleted), it fails to load on my device. I have debugged the code on device and the error is thrown at `PersistentStoreHelper store = PersistentStoreHelper.getInstance();` which gives me `Uncaught exception:java.lang.ClassCastException`

Comment: @Sarah, this is probably what I warned you about (twice).  If you ran the app with the old code, it will have stored data as a `Hashtable`.  Then, if you change the code to what I [posted online](http://pastebin.com/tka4jQvF), the `getInstance()` method will cast the data to a `MyAppsHashtable`.  That will not work.  You will have to delete the old data your app stored, before you changed the code.  I have added a `reset()` method to a [new version of PersistentStoreHelper](http://pastebin.com/Nq7j0Qta).  You can use it **once** to clear out the data on any device/simulator with old data.

Comment: yes I know you mentioned this to me earlier and so I deleted the older Apps and reset my device by plugging out the battery. However, that probably did not clean out the data stored as Hashtable. I am sorry but I do not really understand how to `reset()`. I cannot call this method in my main class since `getInstance()` does not work for me. Can you guide me how to `reset()`.

Comment: @Sarah, that's right.  If you just deleted the app, and did a battery pull, it would not delete the old persistent data.  That's actually the benefit of that kind of storage.  It stays around.  Since the old data stored a `java.util.Hashtable`, it would never be deleted by the device.  See my **Update 2** above.  I decided it would be better just to modify the `PersistentStoreHelper` constructor, to detect this problem, and automatically reset the persistent store.  So, you don't need to call `reset()`.  Just replace the constructor you have with the one I posted above.  Thanks.

Comment: Final version, with the constructor modified, and `reset()` removed, is [posted here](http://pastebin.com/iki1iwgk).

Comment: Thanks you @Nate. Finally able to get it through.

Comment: Great.  Your *persistence* has paid off (a little joke there ... may not translate if English isn't your first language!).